# IOS-XR XML agent ssl

Tags: cisco-ios-xr, cisco-asr

I have enabled xml agent on ASR9k:

```
#show run xml agent ssl
Tue May 20 22:19:11.791 UTC
xml agent ssl
 iteration off
!
```

When I try to connect to port 38752 it gets disconnected with connection reset

```
# openssl s_client -connect 10.104.56.84:38752 
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 225 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

How do I connect to the XML agent with SSL?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The router needs to generate a certificate that it can use to encrypt the communication. See the Cisco configuration guide chapter on "Implementing Secure Socket Layer" here: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k_r5-1/security/configuration/guide/b_syssec_cg51xasr9k/b_syssec_cg51xasr9k_chapter_01001.html

Answer (score 0):

### [Cisco IOS XR XML API Guide, Cisco IOS XR Release 4.1](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios_xr_sw/iosxr_r4-1/xml/programming/guide/xl41apidoc/xl41noti.html)

The k9sec package is required to use the SSL agent. The configuration is rejected during a commit when the k9sec package is not active on the system. When the k9sec package is deactivated after configuring the SSL agent, the agent is not available.